# Should I rewrite all the existing jquery ajax webparts in Typescript or is it better to inject existing jquery in SPFX?

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

We are moving from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint online. We are thinking of migrating existing webparts in 2013 which has jquery - ajax to SPFX client webparts. Now, Do we have to rewrite all the code in Typescript? Can we just inject existing jquery ajax in Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Using Typescript is optional. You are not forced to use it. When creating SharePoint Framework package you can choose not to use any Javascript framework (React, Angular...) and create it in plain Javascript e.g. with jQuery.

So, if your solution is working fine you can use the code as is, ofcourse with some modifications related to SPFX.

For new apps I would definitely recommend to use Typescript.